# Pointer indirection with an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, indirection

I'm trying to have three levels of pointer indirection with an additional pointer pointing to level two of the indirection. This is for a class, and I'm having some real issues. This is what I'm doing.

```
int ***s = new int **[row];
*s = new int *[row];
**s = new int[row];
```

Now if these where just int and not arrays I could do,

```
***s = 1;
```

To store it into the yellow square on my picture, but I don't know how to access the array elements, I have tried a few things and it either crashes or will not compile. Any help, even pointing me in the right direction would be very useful. Thank you.

[image: pointer diagram]

Comment: Not sure what exactly do you want. Are you looking for a 3d array?

Comment: The end game is a two dimensional array, and having the vertical array full of pointers and the columns filled with variables.

Comment: Why not use `int matrix[x][y]` to initialize a two-dimensional array? I don't understand what you mean by having the `vertical array full of pointers`.

Comment: The right direction: [Three star programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: Right but as I said this is for a class, thanks for taking the time to insult rather then read a three sentence post.

Comment: It wasn't meant to insult but to just point out that it gets quite hairy and it's better to steer clear of it. I mistook the term _class_ as the C++ class apparently. I've answered this, hope it helps.

Comment: For efficiency and simplicity it's often better to implement 2d or 3d arrays as a single flat array and use an index calculation. You can wrap this in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created something like this (assume `row` is 2 and type `T`):

```
                           T***
                          +-----+
                          |     |
                          +--/--+
                            /
                           / T**
                       +--/--+-----+
                       |     |     |
                       +-----+--+--+
                       -/       |
                    --/      T* |
                +--/--+-----+ +-+---+-----+
                |     |     | |     |     |
                +-----+-----+ +--+--+-----+
            ----/      -/        |      \---
      -----/        --/      T   |          \--
  +--/--+-----+ +--/--+-----+ +--+--+-----+ +--\--+-----+
  |     |     | |  X  |     | |     |     | |     |     |
  +-----+-----+ +-----+-----+ +-----+-----+ +-----+-----+
```

Every node would point to the next level's first node. Dereferencing every level would give the level next but you've to also take care of the index of the element in the array you want to reach. This, I see, isn't done in your code. For scalars you dereference using `*` while for arrays the array index syntax does dereferencing too apart from choosing the right element. `*` on arrays would just get you the first element always.

To access `X` in the above figure you'd do

```
T** v = u[0];
T* w = v[1];
T x = w[0];
// shorthand for above
x = u[0][1][0];
```

To just have an array at the last level, you should be doing this

```
int*** p = new int**;
*p = new int*;
**p = new int[row];
```

This would just give you █ → █ → █ → █ █ █ …, where `p` itself (the first box) is an automatic variable (usually stored in the stack space) and rest comes from the freestore (usually living in the heap).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc421f3e31e30f8b).

Comment: Jeez. Is this the only way to set up this amount of indirection to an array?

Comment: I showed each step for clarity, added the shorter version now.

Comment: I'm starting to think I'm doing this assignment extremely wrong. Cant I just set up int pointers in the black boxes and have an array at the end in the yellow box?

Comment: Yes, you can. See the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `row = 3` for this example.

```
int ***s;
// s=[?]
// s is an uninitialized variable.
```

```
s = new int **[row];
// s[*] -> [?]
//         [?]
//         [?]
// s points to the first element of an array of size 3.
// The elements are uninitialized.
```

```
*s = new int *[row];
// s=[*] -> [*] -> [?]
//          [?]    [?]
//          [?]    [?]
// We've initialized s[0]. It points to another array of size 3.
// All elements of that array are also uninitialized, along with s[1] and s[2].
```

```
**s = new int[row];
// s=[*] -> [*] -> [*] -> [?]
//          [?]    [?]    [?]
//          [?]    [?]    [?]
// More of the same. s[0][0] is initialized.
// This last array contains uninitialized ints, not pointers.
```

```
***s = 1;
// s=[*] -> [*] -> [*] -> [1]
//          [?]    [?]    [?]
//          [?]    [?]    [?]
// We traverse three levels of pointers (->) and store 1 in the cell.
```

All of this should compile and work fine (as long as you don't access any of the uninitialized elements).

---

`s + 1` points to the second element of the first array.

```
// s=[*] -> [*] -> [*] -> [1]
// s + 1 -> [?]    [?]    [?]
//          [?]    [?]    [?]
```

`*(s + 1)` refers to the cell `[?]` pointed to by `s + 1` in the diagram above. This cell is uninitialized.

`**(s + 1)` tries to dereference a garbage pointer, which is invalid (and often crashes).

Comment: Okay, when I tried this, I used `cout << **s[0];` and I got 1 but when I try to store something lets say in the next offset using `***(s + 1) = 2;` it doesn't work, why not?

Comment: @Mishap Because `*(s + 1)` (also known as `s[1]`) is still uninitialized and not a valid pointer (see my edited answer).